# UPDATE row in grid in extjs 3

Tags: extjs, grid

I have a form and below that a grid. When a add some data in form and click "Insert", it inserts data in grid. When i double click on grid all the data from grid fills up in form. I then change the data. (similar to Ext.data.DataWriter Example)

The problem is I am not able to "UPDATE" row in grid. I am not using datawriter class. But I just simply want to update my grid row with new data.

Is there a way to do this???????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found answer to my question....

its Record class's method:

set( String name, String/Object/Array value ) : void

So you can use it like this:
 record.set('fieldname', 'newvalue');

Thanks everyone....
Regards

Comment: I was just about to say you that. I even had a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/27fRh/